# Can't seem to append text to tag in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, tags, appendtext

I scraped text and HTML link information from a web page and attempted to append it to a `<p>` tag but this did not work. Let me illustrate:

```
data = """
<div class="Answer">
1. BOUNDARIES - EPB &amp; APL&nbsp;<i>(inferior)</i>, EPL&nbsp;<i>(superior).&nbsp;</i><div>2. FLOOR (proximal to distal) - radial styloid =&gt; scaphoid =&gt; trapezium =&gt; 1st MC base.&nbsp;<br /><div>3. CONTENTS - cutaneous branches of radial nerve&nbsp;<i>(on the roof),</i>&nbsp;cephalic vein&nbsp;<i>(begins here),</i>&nbsp;&nbsp;radial artery&nbsp;<i>(on the floor).</i></div></div><div><br /></div><div><img src="paste-27a44c801f0776d91f5f6a16a963bff67f0e8ef3.jpg" /><br /></div><div><b>Image:&nbsp;</b>Case courtesy of Dr Sachintha Hapugoda, &lt;a href="https://radiopaedia.org/"&gt;Radiopaedia.org&lt;/a&gt;. From the case &lt;a href="https://radiopaedia.org/cases/52525"&gt;rID: 52525&lt;/a&gt; [Accessed 15 Nov. 2018].</div>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
image_link = soup.find('div').find('b').next.next
new_tag = soup.new_tag('p', image_link)
print(new_tag.append(image_link))
```

The above returns `None`. What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be

```
new_tag = soup.new_tag('p')
new_tag.append(image_link)
print(new_tag)
```

Comment: He shoots...... He scores! lol There you go again. We need to make a bs4 discord group or something.